# Importing variables scss

Tags: reactjs, sass, css-modules, scss-mixins

I am using scss for the first time

I created a file in src/styles/variables.scss

```
$background-color: #323132;
```

Then on src/components/MyComponent.module.scss

```
@use "src/styles/variables";

.content {
  background-color: variables.$background-color;  
}
```

And I get

```
SassError: Invalid CSS after "...olor: variables": expected expression (e.g. 1px, bold), was ".$background-color;"
        on line 14 of src/components/MyComponent.module.scss
>>   background-color: variables.$background-color;
```

I can't find what is wrong? thank you

Answer (score 1, accepted):

Just import your variables instead and use directly

```
@import "src/styles/variables";

.content {
  background-color: $background-color;  
}
```

Comment: Hi, but why is @use not working? the docs say import will get deprecated....

Comment: Yes, but if you read further than the first sentence you would know that: `Note that only Dart Sass currently supports @use. Users of other implementations must use the @import rule instead.`. Source: https://sass-lang.com/documentation/at-rules/import